# How to freeze a pageBlock?

Tags: visualforce, pageblock

Most of the posts I went through talk about freezing a column in a pageBlockTable and seems like there is now a new 'floating headers' feature in one of the recent releases. But, I would like to freeze a 'pageBlock'. Please see attached image. The section in the left (pageBlock) is for Searching which I would like to remain frozen/static/always-visible/stay-still although the user scrolls right. The right section (pageBlockTable within a pageBlock) is to display the search results, which would contain about 50 fields shouldn't be frozen.

I don't know where/how to start so I have no code to share. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be great. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does my suggestion solve your issue?

Comment: Actually, it did not. It squeezed the right section to 250px wide and had no scroll bar at the bottom. I was trying to improve on your suggestion, but had no luck so far.

Comment: ahh yes, it worked just fine when I had tested it using some other components, but it seems like PageBlock/PageBlockSection/PageBlockTable do not want to play nicely... Perhaps if you wrapped it in an apex:outputPanel or a div which uses these style properties?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using CSS. If you give the right block a fixed width or max width, you should be able to also give it an overflow: scroll behavior. For example, you might give that pageblock (or maybe just the table) a styleclass with the following properties

```
max-width: 250px;
overflow-x: auto; //for horizontal scroll
```

You can also use `overflow-y: auto;` for vertical scroll too if you want.